# Scala, Sbt - download wrong version of library even if it is set in build.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-cats, zio

I have a weird problem with `Sbt`. I have a `Scala` `zio` version set to `1.0.12` in `build.sbt`:

```
 val zio = "1.0.12"
```

But when I ran application with `sbt` it downloaded `zio` in version `2.x` (screen):
[image]

I have no idea why. I removed `.ivy2` and `.sbt` directories from user directory. I restarted intellij many times, invalided cached. Even with clear project it always downloads version `2.0.0`. Whole code is inspected with this version.

Other zio related lib's versions I use:

```
val scalaVersion        = "2.13.8"
val zio                 = "1.0.12"
val zioInteropCats      = "3.2.9.0"
val zioInteropLog       = "1.0.1"
```

Do you have any ideas why it works like this? I do not need to use `ZIO` in newest version.

Comment: Nvm, tapir was in too high version. Changed to `0.19.4` and works fine now

Answer (score 0):

I see in your comment you already solved this, but here's how you'd solve it in general:

This kind of thing is caused when two of your dependencies require *different* versions of a library. Your explicitly-set version is being "evicted" in favor of a higher version that something else requires

You can find this info by running `sbt evicted`. If your sbt version is recent (as of 2022), it should be able to use the `versionScheme` for scala libraries (if they are versions published after the feature was added) in order to alert you with an error when an eviction is likely to be incompatible.

The solution as you've found is to locate the dependency which is bringing in the incompatible version and then resolve the conflict by changing the version of either that dependency or the others